# Javascript has killed my clipboard! Can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I needed a way to force the cursor to the left whenever the user clicked on an ASP.Net textbox, so I threw in these two Javascript functions:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //Add this to the textbox: OnFocus="txtEPro_OnFocus()" 
    function txtEPro_OnFocus() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
        elem.value = "";
        elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

        var event = event || window.event;
        if (event.button == '0') {
            // it was a right click
            setTimeout(function () {
                elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
            }, 0);

        }
        // alert("Hello there"); 
    }

</script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).mousedown(function () {
        //If it's a right-click, kill the menu, set the cursor to the left and show a message
        if (event.button == 2 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= txtePro.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        alert('right click not allowed');
        return false;
        }
        //If it's a left-click, just set the cursor to the left
        if (event.button == 1 && event.srcElement.id == '<%= txtePro.ClientID %>') {
            var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
            elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'll state the obvious: **I am not a Javascript coder**.  So, anyway, what's happening is that for some users, they can't use Ctrl+V to paste a value into the box.  One of the functions is preventing the right-click menu from coming up (which is what I wanted) so they can't use that to paste either.

The *txtEPro_OnFocus* function was something I mostly found on SO that said you needed to use a timer to get the cursor to go to the left.  I honestly don't even know if it works the way it was intended, but the textbox doesn't work properly when I comment that code out.

This all stems from an issue I'm having with a masked textbox; if a user right-clicks in the middle of the mask and pastes a value, it doesn't register properly.  So, I'm using the above code to force the cursor to the left when the user clicks in the textbox.

Can anyone tell me why my clipboard might not be responding to Ctrl+V, or can you help me with my Javascript so that it will work properly?  We are using IE9 (this is mandated by the company and we can't change it even if we wanted to) in a Windows 7 environment.

Comment: Did you actually experience the issue yourself? Is there a chance that the masked textbox denies the pasted value because it's not valid or not valid when prefixed to the text present in the textbox before (which is what happens when you paste with text inside), and users just reported paste isn't working?

Comment: It worked for me, but a user was sharing their screen and did exactly what I had done and it didn't work for them.  Does my code look sound?  As stated above, I'm not proficient at all with Javascript so it wouldn't surprise me if there was a better way to do what I've done.

Comment: By "sharing their screen", do you mean they were using some kind of virtual desktop? This sounds like it could be a problem with mouse/keyboard input on said virtual desktop rather than a problem with JavaScript.

Comment: It was actually a Lync session.  Lync is Microsoft's version of Instant Messenger, and you can share part or all of your desktop if you want to.  The user was having the issue prior to sharing their desktop.